# What permissions to add for AWS RDS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-iam

I am trying to create a mysql database on AWS RDS. I created a standard free tier database, which didn't work because i did not have `iam:CreateServiceLinkedRole` permissions. I addressed this by adding this to my permissions:

```
{
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Action": "iam:CreateServiceLinkedRole",
    "Resource": "arn:aws:iam::*:role/aws-service-role/*"
}
```

This worked and I was able to create the db. However, I deleted the db to create a new one with different parameters and I am getting this error. What permissions do I need to allow? Essentially, I want full access to AWS RDS.

```
Your request to create DB instance database-1 didn't work.
User: arn:aws:iam::111111111111:user/connor.eaton is not authorized to perform: iam:CreateRole on resource: arn:aws:iam::111111111111:role/rds-monitoring-role
```

Comment: `iam:CreateRole` is what the error says

Comment: I see that. What should the json be to fix this? Its not clear to me.

Comment: Change the json in your post to `"Action": ["iam:CreateServiceLinkedRole", "iam:CreateRole"]`

Comment: I changed the json to this: `{
    "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": "Action": ["iam:CreateServiceLinkedRole", "iam:CreateRole"]
    "Resource": "arn:aws:iam::*:role/aws-service-role/*"
}` but it breaks on "Resource". What should "Resource" be?

Comment: `*`, but also you added "Action" twice. it's not valid json anymore

Comment: Is this what you mean? { "Effect": "Allow", "Action": ["iam:CreateServiceLinkedRole", "iam:CreateRole"], "Resource": "*" }

Comment: Yeah, that looks correct